# Google AdSense is not reviewing the URL I submitted, using my local development URL instead

Tags: google, google-adsense, virtualhost

I'm very confused. I'm trying to get my site (let's just say www.example.com) approved for Google AdSense. I submitted the application using "**www**.example.com" and I got a reply from AdSense saying my application was rejected because "**dev**.example.com" was unavailable.

"dev.example.com" is my local virtual host that is set up in Apache and my Windows `hosts` file. It is NOT a public URL and will not work anywhere except my computer. My site uses relative paths, so "dev.example.com" is not in the source code anywhere.

My two questions are HOW is AdSense getting my local virtual host URL, and WHY is it using that URL for approval instead of the URL I submitted in my application?

Comment: Have you checked .htaccess?

Comment: Yep, .htaccess is quite normal. It only has code to rewrite to `http://www.mysite.com` if the user requests `http://mysite.com`.

Comment: How about [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21905784/1040562)

Comment: dev.mysite.com already doesn't exist (only on my computer). That's why Google denied my AdSense application, because they said dev.mysite.com doesn't exist. Blocking that subdomain won't do anything because the subdomain already doesn't exist.

Comment: Are you sure you put the correct URL in your application?   I suspect you accidentally pasted the wrong thing when you applied.  You can apply again and make sure you have it right.

Comment: I'm almost 100% positive, but obviously you never know. The thing is, the reason they declined the application is they said `dev.mysite.com/search?lang=en` was "down or unavailable". In order for them to get to `/search?lang=en` from the root URL, they would have to click into the Search section and then click the language toggle. How could they click into Search from a non-existent home page? Unless `dev.mysite.com` got indexed somehow, but that URL doesn't even exist on the internet. This makes no sense!

Comment: They do send a crawler out to your site.  Another possibility is that your live site is referring to your dev site somewhere.  I've had links to my dev server leak out to onto my live site by mistake before.

Comment: All my URLs are generated by PHP, so they're either "dev.mysite.com" or "www.mysite.com".

Comment: Just realized I never followed up on this :) I never figured out how they got that URL, but eventually the correct URL was crawled. Still baffled...

Answer (score 1):

The AdSense crawler wouldn't know about your dev site unless you told it about it somehow.  Either:

- You submitted your dev site accidentally when applying for AdSense
- Your live site links to  your dev site somehow

To fix this:

1. Resubmit your AdSense application and make sure to specify the correct site
2. Run a crawler against your own live site and make sure it never tries to get to your dev site.